# how to merge two html files through tornado

Tags: python, html, render, tornado

I have two HTML files( Home1.html and Home2.html ). I want to merge these two HTML files and serve it as one page using Tornado framework. But I get an error :"`Runtime Error: Cannot render() after finish()`" when I tried the following:

```
class Setup(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.render("Home1.html")
    self.render("Home2.html")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/setup",Setup ),

])
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(5500)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to learn how templating works. Read this page on the docs to learn more: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/templates.html#template-syntax

After that, you can find the complete template syntax reference on this page: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/template.html#syntax-reference

Anyway, you can *"merge"* two templates and render them as one by using the `{% include %}` template tag. Example:

Your `Home1.html` template should look roughly like this:

```html
<html>
    <!-- do something -->
    {% include 'Home2.html' %}
    <!-- do something else -->
</html>
```

Then render only the `Home1.html` from your request handler.

This answer is far from perfect. You'll have to invest some time to actually learn about templates.